# Right align a part of the string with Bash

Tags: bash, printf, right-align

I would like to right align the memory usage while keeping the services left aligned.
I'm using `printf '%-1s %-25s %s\n' $ok $service $memory` and the result is:

```
[OK] gitea                     142.2M
[OK] mariadb                   73.0M
[OK] nginx                     9.5M
```

I would like something more like this:

```
[OK] gitea                     142.2M
[OK] mariadb                    73.0M
[OK] nginx                       9.5M
```

---

**Edit**
What about rendering these strings?

```
sdusage=88
cpuusage=5
swapusage=44
temp="50"
sdusagetext="SD usage is $sdusage%"  
cpuusagetext="CPU usage is $cpuusage%"  
swapusagetext="SWAP usaage is $swapusage%"
temptext="Temperature is $temp°C"
```

Is there a better approach than this one?

```
printf '%-1s %-3s %-26s %6s\n' $sdusagetext
printf '%-1s %-3s %-25s %6s\n' $cpuusagetext
printf '%-1s %-3s %-24s %6s\n' $swapusagetext
printf '%-1s %-24s %6s\n' $temptext
```

Comment: Try `%6s` instead of `%s`???

Comment: To align on the decimal dot `printf '%-1s %-25s %6s.%s\n' "$ok" "$service" "${memory%%.*}" "${memory##*.}"`

Comment: @oguzismail thank you, can you please read the edit?